# Less Celery task logging

Tags: elasticsearch, celery, elastic-stack, django-celery

We use Celery for managing tasks in our Python Django application.
We also use Django `structlog` for log messages printed by Celery.
We ingest these messages to ElasticSearch via Logstash, and noticed that vast majority of messages we get are these 2:

> Received task: %s
>
> Task %(name)s[%(id)s] succeeded in %(runtime)ss: %(return_value)s

Celery dumps them with the **INFO** logging level.
Is there any way to change just these messages to **DEBUG** level?
So that we can still run celery with `-l INFO` and see other **INFO** messages, but not these ones?

## Update

For the 2nd log messagee.

After quick reading of:

- https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/internals/reference/celery.app.trace.html
- https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/trace.html

Without much knowledge of Celery, Django and structlog, would something like this work?

```
LOGGING = {
...
'loggers': {
        'celery.app.trace': {
          'handlers': ['null'],
          'propagate': False,
         }
...
}
```

Comment: if you can post more info like which particular ES class/package/module you want to log in DEBUG mode, we can help you

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. DEBUG \ INFO levels - are on Celery logger level, not ElasticSearch. I suppose I can filter them our in Logstash, but ideally I'd prefer Celery not to print them at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to ignore only those two messages:

**init**.py

```
import celery
from unittest import mock

app = celery.Celery()


from celery.app import trace
old_info = trace.info
trace.info = mock.Mock()


class MyTask(celery.Task):
    Strategy = '61242484.strategy:my_default'


@app.task(base=MyTask)
def test():
    print("123")


test.apply_async()
```

strategy.py

```
from unittest import mock
from celery.worker.strategy import default


def my_default(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['info'] = mock.Mock()
    return default(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi Anton. Many thanks for your reply. Any chance you can explain how it works? I don't have much knowledge of Celery or structlog, so it's all a bit cryptic for me.

Comment: I just looked at the sources of celery, and understand how logging could be avoided. your solution to ignore celery.app.trace is better.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using that config for structlog, but didn't completely test it yet

Answer (score 0):

@Anton Pomieshchenko, thanks for your help, it was very useful for me.
However, I found a bug with the `my_default` method

With this:

```
def strategy(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['info'] = mock.Mock()

    from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
    logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
    logger.info(f'test: {list(args)}')
    logger.info(f'test: {[type(arg) for arg in list(args)]}')

    return celery.worker.strategy.default(*args, **kwargs)
```

I get that:

```
INFO 2022-10-16 00:19:40,673 celery_app 41 139675281467200 test: [<@task: add_test_iterator of napsedjango at 0x7f08ac73f610>, <@task: add_test_iterator of napsedjango at 0x7f08ac73f610>, <Celery napsedjango at 0x7f08ac73f610>, <Consumer: celery@06d4f16e55fb (running)>]
INFO 2022-10-16 00:19:40,674 celery_app 41 139675281467200 test: [<class 'napsedjango._users.tasks.add_test_iterator'>, <class 'napsedjango._users.tasks.add_test_iterator'>, <class 'celery.app.base.Celery'>, <class 'celery.worker.consumer.consumer.Consumer'>]
CRITICAL 2022-10-16 00:19:40,674 worker 41 139675281467200 Unrecoverable error: TypeError("default() got multiple values for argument 'info'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 332, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/tasks.py", line 26, in start
    c.update_strategies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 561, in update_strategies
    self.strategies[name] = task.start_strategy(self.app, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 412, in start_strategy
    return instantiate(self.Strategy, self, app, consumer, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 49, in instantiate
    return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/config/celery_app.py", line 44, in strategy
    return celery.worker.strategy.default(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: default() got multiple values for argument 'info'
```

On row 1 and 2 (logger), we can see that there are the task 2 times in `args`. This does not correspond to the entry of [celery.worker.strategy.default()](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.worker.strategy.html)

To fix this issue:

```
def strategy(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['info'] = mock.Mock()
    return celery.worker.strategy.default(*args[1:], **kwargs)
```